# Why when I run this code return_ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pdf, full-text-search

I'm trying to extract just some parts of an invoice in pdf format. So I'm using the code below. The problem is when I run the code, returns AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' and I cant see why. the complete message is:

numero_factura = re.search(r'N°\s*(d+)', text).group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

and it happens with this four variables:
numero_factura
cantidad
costo_unitario_fact
valor_total_fact

please help !

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
path = r'C:/Users/' +  os.getlogin()  +'/OneDrive - Falabella/Documentos - Desarrollo Logistico/Proyectos Desarrollo Interno/Proyectos Internos'
sys.path.insert(0, path)
import PyPDF2
import tabula
import re
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pdfplumber
#import EjecutarQuery as EQ 
#from datetime import datetime
#from datetime import timedelta
#import ToolsBI

#%%
#Leemos archivo excel de Base
path = r'C:/Users/'+  os.getlogin()  +'/OneDrive - Falabella/Documentos - Desarrollo Logistico/Proyectos Desarrollo Interno/Proyectos Internos/Confimación y Facturación Apple/Base proveedor/Base-prueba.xlsx'
detalle_base = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name="Base")
detalle_base = detalle_base.reindex(columns = ['Factura', 'New OC', 'PRODUCTO', 'NOMBRE', 'Units', 'CAJAS', 'SKU Falabella', 'Costo Unitario', 'Monto total', 'Diferencia Informada', 'Comentarios'])

def extract_pdf_data(file_names):
    all_data = []
    for file_name in file_names:
        with pdfplumber.open(file_name) as pdf:
            page = pdf.pages[0]
            text = page.extract_text()
            numero_factura = re.search(r'N°\s*(d\+)', text).group(1)
            cantidad = re.search(r'Cant.\s*(d\+)', text).group(1)
            costo_unitario_fact = re.search(r'Valor unitario\s*(d\+)', text).group(1)
            valor_total_fact = re.search(r'Valor\s*(d\+)', text).group(1)
            data = [numero_factura, cantidad, costo_unitario_fact, valor_total_fact]
            all_data.append(data)
    return all_data

def convert_pdfs_to_excel(directory, excel_file_name, excel_path):
    file_names = [os.path.join(directory, f) for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.pdf')]
    all_data = extract_pdf_data(file_names)
    flat_data = [item for sublist in all_data for item in sublist]
    df = pd.DataFrame(flat_data, columns=['Numero Factura', 'Cantidad', 'Costo Unitario', 'Valor Total'])
    df.to_excel(excel_file_name, index=False)
    
convert_pdfs_to_excel(r'C:/Users/'+ os.getlogin() +'/OneDrive - Falabella/Documentos - Desarrollo Logistico/Proyectos Desarrollo Interno/Proyectos Internos/Confimación y Facturación Apple/Facturas Apple', 'datos.xlsx', 'C:/Users/'+ os.getlogin() +'/OneDrive - Falabella/Documentos - Desarrollo Logistico/Proyectos Desarrollo Interno/Proyectos Internos/Confimación y Facturación Apple')
```

I try the code above. I'm expecting that the code returns an excel file with just a few data from the invoice .pdf. All the .pdf files are in a same path.

Comment: Might the [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and [Match objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) documentation help?

Comment: But the thing is that I need the information, I don't need nones, and transform all the invoice to an excel file, doesn't return an organized file.